# spring mvc @RequestParam The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a big problem with my RequestParam. I read some other questions with the same problem but I checked the syntax a hundred times and I don't know what is wrong in my code. I'm new in spring and it would be really nice if somebody can check my code and help me to find my mistake.

I have a jsp file with a form tag. In that form the user can choose what kind of chart he wants to create.
My jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form   action="piechart" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="pieChart" value="pie">pie<br>
<input type="radio" name="barChart" value="bar">bar<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<img src="/piechart" />
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
package net.codejava.springmvc;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;
import org.jfree.util.Rotation;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
public class ResultController {


      private double value1 = 20.0;
      private double value2 = 20.0;
      private double value3 = 20.0;
      private double value4 = 20.0;
      private double value5 = 20.0;

      private String answer1 = "very good: " + value1 + "%";
      private String answer2 = "good: " + value2 + "%";
      private String answer3 = "bad: " + value3 + "%";
      private String answer4 = "very bad: " + value4 + "%";
      private String answer5 ="no answer: " + value5 + "%";

      @RequestMapping(value="/result", method= RequestMethod.GET)
      public String test() {
          return "jsp/result/pieChart";
      }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/piechart", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public void createChart(@RequestParam("pie") String pie, @RequestParam("bar") String bar, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        PieDataset pieDataset = createDataset();
        JFreeChart pieChart = createChart(pieDataset, "Question");
        try {
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), pieChart, 750, 400);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    /** * set Data*/

    public  PieDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
        result.setValue(answer1, 20);
        result.setValue(answer2, 20);
        result.setValue(answer3, 20);
        result.setValue(answer4, 20);
        result.setValue(answer5, 20 );
        return result;

    }


/** * Creates a chart */

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset, String title) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title,   
            dataset,                
            true,                   
            true,
            false);

        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setStartAngle(290); 
        plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
        plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.9f);
        plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        plot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        plot.setLabelLinksVisible(true);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(null);
        plot.setInteriorGap(0.04);
        plot.setOutlineVisible(true);
        Color[] colors = {new Color(153,204,255), new Color(153,153,255), new Color(204,153,255), new Color(255,153,255), new Color(255,153,204)}; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            plot.setSectionPaint(i, colors[i]);
        }



        return chart;


    }

}
```

At the moment it is only possible to create a piechart. I would be happy when the @RequestParam would show my piechart after I choose the radiobutton.

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you make your problem more clear? Is the chart actually shown when posting the form? Is something else not working?

Comment: the chart is shown when i delete the requestParam and only use the requestMapping.

Comment: and it is also shown when i use RequestParam (value="Pie", required=false) or RequestBody.
I also tried request.getParam("pie") but it is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the names you are using in `@RequestParam` to reflect the names you are using in the form.

`public void createChart(@RequestParam(value ="pieChart", required = false) String pie, @RequestParam(value = "barChart", required = false) String bar, HttpServletResponse response)`

Since the browser will not allow both the radios to be selected, we need to add `required = false` to both.

Inside `createChart` you will need to make sure that at least one of the arguments is filled

Comment: Thank you very much! But now there is another problem. It is only working when I use one @RequestParam("pieChart")
when I use the second one Request("barChart") it seems like spring gets a little bit crazy. When I chosse the first one (pieChart) he says that he can't find barChart. But the url param is pieChart. 
Do you know something about that kind of problem?

Comment: That is because the browser cannot send both values. Check my updated answer

Comment: that makes sense. Now it is working with both parameters. Thank you for you help.Now I understand how this process is working.

Comment: No problem! It would be good if you accept the answer as correct in order to help future readers of the question. Thanks!